# What strategy to use: store additional informational field in main table or in separate with on-to-one/many relation?

Tags: entity-framework, database-design

I have main entity and sometimes customer want new fields in this entity.

As them used as informational and never be as criteria in queries I think that storing them in main table may be worse practice (especially updating schema each update).

What if organise additional table:

```
create table ENTITY_FIELD (
  ENTITY_ID,
  FIELD_NAME,
  FIELD_TYPE,
  FIELD_VALUE,
primary key (ENTITY_ID, FIELD_NAME));
```

and join one-to-one with `ENTITY` table on `f.ENTITY_ID = e.ID and f.FIELD_NAME = 'field1'` when I need `field1` field? Like:

```
select e.*, f1.FIELD_VALUE, f2.FIELD_VALUE from ENTITY e
  left join ENTITY_FIELD f1 on f1.ENTITY_ID = e.ID and f1.FIELD_NAME = 'field1'
  left join ENTITY_FIELD f2 on f2.ENTITY_ID = e.ID and f2.FIELD_NAME = 'field2'
```

Or add fields to `ENTITY` and live with  100-200 fields in?

How about hold all fields in separate table:

```
create table ENTITY_FIELD (
  ENTITY_ID,
  FIELD1,
  FIELD2,
  FIELD3,
  FIELD4,
  ...
primary key (ENTITY_ID));
```

so you only join on `f.ENTITY_ID = e.IE`? Like:

Like:

```
select e.*, f.FIELD1, f.FIELD2 from ENTITY e, ENTITY_FIELD f
  where e.ID = f.ENTITY_ID
```

I use Oracle/Java/Hibernate but seems that question about general design.

Answer (score 1):

There is really no right or wrong answer and I guess you should employ a method that reduces the need to recompile and or remap your entities.

I have a personal rule for this. If an option dictates business rule logic or program flow it should be a type field in a main entity table and would require a recompilation. If you are storing arbitrary values such as ui preferences and size info, custom images, user parameter values, or custom labels, basically things that do not require values and ideally have default values, and more importantly, the system will function with or without the values being set then you can put these in some kind of setting table. I use two straightforward `UserSettings` and `UserSettingsConfiguration` tables similar to your approach above.

```
UserSetting
----------
UserSettingID(PK),
SettingName,
Description
Category

UserSettingConfiguration
------------------------
UserSettingConfigurationID(PK),
UserSettingID (FK UserSetting.UserSettingID),
UserID (FK)
Value
```